# karma jasmine require unexpected token import

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

how can i get data from my javascript file in my jasmine file ?
now when i do this with import or require i get errors.

is this possible for do this? because later on i want use jasmine for my angular2 projects

thanks a lot

config file = karma.config.js

```
  // Karma configuration
// Generated on Tue Feb 21 2017 14:41:05 GMT+0100 (Romance (standaardtijd))

module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({

    // base path that will be used to resolve all patterns (eg. files, exclude)
    basePath: '',


    // frameworks to use
    // available frameworks: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-adapter
    frameworks: ['jasmine'],


    // list of files / patterns to load in the browser
    files: [
        {pattern: "./test.js"}
    ],


    // list of files to exclude
    exclude: [
    ],


    // preprocess matching files before serving them to the browser
    // available preprocessors: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-preprocessor
    preprocessors: {
    },


    // test results reporter to use
    // possible values: 'dots', 'progress'
    // available reporters: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-reporter
    reporters: ['progress'],


    // web server port
    port: 9876,


    // enable / disable colors in the output (reporters and logs)
    colors: true,


    // level of logging
    // possible values: config.LOG_DISABLE || config.LOG_ERROR || config.LOG_WARN || config.LOG_INFO || config.LOG_DEBUG
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,


    // enable / disable watching file and executing tests whenever any file changes
    autoWatch: true,


    // start these browsers
    // available browser launchers: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-launcher
    browsers: ['Chrome'],


    // Continuous Integration mode
    // if true, Karma captures browsers, runs the tests and exits
    singleRun: false,

    // Concurrency level
    // how many browser should be started simultaneous
    concurrency: Infinity
  })
}
```

js file = js.js

```
    function test() {
    return 'dit is een test';
}
```

jasmine file = test.js

```
    import {t} from './js.js';

describe('text',function () {
   it('text',function () {
       expect(t.test()).toBe('dit is een test');
   });
```

});